# Show that for every odd integer, $n^3 - n^2 - 5n +5$ is divisible by 8 using modulo arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic

**Problem:**

Show that for every odd integer,  $n^3 - n^2 - 5n +5$ is divisible by 8. using modulo arithmetic

I'm not sure how to use the modulo arithmetic concept to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

$n^3-n^2-5n+5=n^2(n-1)-5(n-1)=(n-1)(n^2-5)=(2p)(4p^2+4p+1-5)=(2p)(4p^2+4p-4)=8p(p^2+p-1)$

Answer (score 1):

$$n^3-n^2-5n+5=(n^2-5)n-(n^2-5)=(n^2-5)(n-1)=(n^2-1-4)(n-1)=(n+1)(n-1)^2-4(n-1)$$

If $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ and $n-1$ are both even, so $8\mid(n+1)(n-1)^2$ and $8\mid4(n-1)$.

Comment: Interesting factorisation.

Answer (score 0):

You could factor this into $n^2(n-1)-5(n-1)=(n^2-5)(n-1)$ now check the four cases when $$n\equiv 1\pmod{8}\\n\equiv 3\pmod{8}\\n\equiv 5\pmod{8}\\n\equiv 7\pmod{8}$$